# How do I display a user friendly error when Spring is unable to validate a model's java.util.Date field?

Tags: spring, validation, date, model, error-handling

I'm using Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE.  I want to display an error message on my JSP if my date field isn't formatted properly.  I thought I'd followed all the right steps.  I binder a converter in my controller …

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) {
    final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(Contract.DATE_FORMAT);
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);

    // true passed to CustomDateEditor constructor means convert empty String to null
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
...
}
```

I have included these error messages in my messages.properties file (included in the Spring application context)

```
typeMismatch.activationDate=The activation date format should be of the form MM/dd/yyyy
typeMismatch.sampleUserForm.activationDate=The activation date format should be of the form MM/dd/yyyy
```

Here's the model I'm using:

```
public class SampleUserForm
{

    private String userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String url;
    private String password;
    private String confirmPassword;
    private State state;
    private java.util.Date activationDate;
    private java.util.Date expirationDate;
    private List<Product> products;
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
```

And here is the error message I receive when I submit my form with a poorly-formatted date …

```
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'sampleUserForm' on field 'activationDate': rejected value [1900]; codes [typeMismatch.sampleUserForm.activationDate,typeMismatch.activationDate,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [sampleUserForm.activationDate,activationDate]; arguments []; default message [activationDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'activationDate'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date: "1900"]
    org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:111)
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:75)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:156)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

What else do I need to do/check to trap for a badly-formatted date?  I would prefer to display a friendly error message to the user rather than the page gracelessly dying.

Here is the controller method that is supposed to handle the form.  Notice I have already included a BindingResult.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView save(final HttpServletRequest request,
                         final SampleUserForm sampleUserForm,
                         final Model model,
                         final BindingResult result) 
{
    String nextPage = "sampleusers/add";
    m_sampleUserFormValidator.validate(sampleUserForm, result);
    if (!result.hasErrors())
    {
       ... process the model and determine the next page ...
    }   // if 

    return new ModelAndView(nextPage);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See: [Spring @Valid validator not invoked properly (Roo, Hibernate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916623/spring-valid-validator-not-invoked-properly-roo-hibernate).

Short story is changing the controller method signature from

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView save(final HttpServletRequest request,
                     final SampleUserForm sampleUserForm,
                     final Model model,
                     final BindingResult result)
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView save(final HttpServletRequest request,
                         final Model model,
                         final SampleUserForm sampleUserForm,
                         final BindingResult result)
```

fixed everything.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you should be binding the form into one of your `POST` methods using `@ModelAttribute`. In the same method bind a `BindingResult bindingResult` and all the binding errors should be captured into this `bindingResult` object. Inside the method, you should be able to check for

`if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {`

and take appropriate action.

Comment: I get this error before my controller's POST method is invoked -- in other words, it never even reaches the state where I check the BindingResult for errors.

Comment: Adding the BindingResults as the next parameter after the one annotated with @ModelAttribute in your controller method solves the problem, exactly as Teja decribed it. Without the binding results, spring throws the exception. With the binding results it will give you a chance to react on the problems.

Comment: Hi, The BindingResult was already in the controller method.  I have included the controller method signature in the question.  Other types of error messages are displayed back fine, it is only these date conversions that are throwing the exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the error is when you formats the data. To confirm that you need debug your application and check date value. And another good practice would be to believe that you configure a standard format for your application.

Follow the example below:

```
 @Configuration
 public class ApplicationContext {

    @Bean
    public FormattingConversionService conversionService() {

            // Use the DefaultFormattingConversionService but do not register
            // defaults
            DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService(false);

            // Ensure @NumberFormat is still supported
            conversionService.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory());

            // Register date conversion with a specific global format
            DateFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateFormatterRegistrar();
            registrar.setFormatter(new DateFormatter("dd/MM/yyyy")); // define your format
            registrar.registerFormatters(conversionService);

            return conversionService;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, clearly there is a formatting issue because I try and parse "1900" using the date string "MM/dd/yyyy".  How do I incorporate your "FormattingConversionService" into my @initBinder and how do I then display the error message represented by the code "typeMismatch.sampleUserForm.activationDate" on my JSP?

Comment: With FormattingConversionService you don't need to convert data in binder. To make this method work you just need to create a class with methods and annotations within a package that is scanned.

And try  use this example in your JSP:
<fmt:formatDate pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" value="${model.activationDate}" var="activationDate" />

Answer (score 0):

annotate a method on that controller class with this class/method level annotation:

```
@ExceptionHandler(BindException.class)
public String handleBindExcption(/*flexible parameters*/ ){
    //codes goes here
    return "view"; //view name or modelAndView 
}
```

more [info](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
`class DateBinderImpl` extends PropertyEditorSupport {



 public void setAsText(String text)
        throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
if(text.isEmpty()){

        Datelistener dateString = new Datelistener ();
        dateString.setValue("");
        setValue(dateString); setValue is method of PropertyEditorSupport
return;
    }
// for other date check condition use SimpleDateFormat class

public String getAsText()
    {
        Datelistener dateString = (Datelistener) getValue();
        if(dateString.getDate.isEmpty()){
            return "";

}


public class   Datelistener {
private String date;
public Datelistener ()
    {

    }
//setter and getter for date;

}

public class TestModel{
  private Datelistener date;
// gettter and setter for date




}
@InitBinder
 public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder)
    {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Datelistener, new DateBinderImpl());

    }

private boolean checkClientSideValidation(TestModel model, BindingResult bindingResult) {
Datelistener  dateobject=model.getDate(); // now you can obtained binded date value.
dateobject.getDate().isEmpty(){
 bindingResult.rejectValue("date;", "", new Object[] {""}, "");
            return true;
}
```

You can see this link for more 
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?58933-Handle-excpetions-from-custom-property-editor-spring-2-5
http://www.codercorp.com/blog/spring/registering-propertyeditorss-with-spring-for-custom-objects-example.html

Comment: Hi, I'm a little hazy on what you're explaining.  I understand the PropertyEditorSupport class can convert a string to a java.util.Date object, but what is the variable "error= yourerror;" and how do I make a parse exception translate into the user seeing the error code "typeMismatch.sampleUserForm.activationDate" displayed on the JSP?

Comment: CustomDateEditor of spring throws parsing exception.So after exception it terminates.So control is not passing to yours controller.What you need to do is yo need to extend PropertyEditorSupport  .In yours extended code do not throw exception catch it .

Answer (score 0):

BindingResult Argument should be next to Model being validated. Eg

```
 public void checkout(
                         @Valid @ModelAttribute("legalContactDetails") LegalContactDetails legalContactDetails,
                         BindingResult legalContactDetailsResult,
                         @Valid @ModelAttribute("researchIntent") ResearchIntent researchIntent,
                         BindingResult researchIntentResult)
```